# How do I pull a package / deb file from an apt server on a mac?

Tags: macos, apt

How can I programmatically pull down the latest deb file for an apt package and extract the contents in order to be able to access a script therein?  I want this to work on a mac with the standard suite of tools (i.e. no apt-get or apt-cache).

Background: My simulation project uses client code to execute.  The host simulation tool runs on a linux environment and is managed through an internal apt server.  One colleague is using apt-get on his linux box to install the package and then is sending a single file to us.  I want our client to do this programmatically in a way that will work on mac clients.  I have dry run the process (see example answer), but I am surprised nobody has talked about this already.

Any recommendations on how best to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried to convince myself of feasibility before asking.

Get link info on linux system: `apt-cache show s-package-name`
From this, I found the line:

```
Filename: pool/main/s/s-package-name/s-package-name_0.2.0-variousNumbers3_all.deb
```

From this, I was able to do the following:

```
wget http://aptserver/pool/main/s/s-package-name/s-package-name_0.2.0-variousNumbers3_all.deb
ar vx s-package-name_0.2.0-variousNumbers3_all.deb
tar -zxvf data.tar.gz
```

That in turn extracted a folder `opt`, which contains a folder with the organization name (hereafter `sOrg`), in which is a folder named package-name that has the file I want.

Finally, I looked back at `http://aptserver/pool/main/s/s-package-name/` in my browser and I see something like:

```
s-package-name_0.2.0-variousNumbers0_all.deb    12-Jul-2013 22:40   2.5M     
s-package-name_0.2.0-variousNumbers1_all.deb    16-Jul-2013 15:30   2.6M     
s-package-name_0.2.0-variousNumbers2_all.deb    22-Aug-2013 23:45   2.6M     
s-package-name_0.2.0-variousNumbers3_all.deb    12-Sep-2013 22:21   2.6M
```

This makes me think that I should be able to just look at that using a web query and determine the name of the latest deb file (without going to a linux box).

I'm ready to automate this, but thought I'd see if this is solved first or if there are better ways of attacking it.

Comment: well if you want to do package management you have you can do the legacy fink which used debs or macports or homebrew... since it seems like you don't, then why don't you want to use the Mac installer?

Comment: I'm not trying to install the package.  The package is an application that runs on our headless servers.  I just want to pull a single text file out of the package (a script) so that we don't need to separately distribute just that file.